# ¿Como obtengo valor de retorno de una sentencia sql desde mi controller java?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-jdbc

Muy buenas, tengo el sgte codigo donde verifico si un usuario existe en mi tabla, todo bien hasta alli, el problema es que no puedo distinguir si ese mismo usuario encontrado es de tipo ADMIN o de tipo OPERADOR, columna que existe en la propia tabla, al enviar la consulta deberia retornarme si es admin o operador, quisiera saber como obtener ese valor en una variable local en java para a partir de ello direccionarlo a la vista correspondiente.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "vistas/validar.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView getValidar(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws SQLException {
        usuario = req.getParameter("usuario");
        pasword = req.getParameter("pasword");
        //Iterator<String> it= datos.iterator();
        String sql = "select * from usuario where usuario='" + usuario + "' and pasword='" + pasword + "'";
        datos = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);
        if (datos.isEmpty()) {

            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/index.htm");
        } else {
            sql = "select tipo from usuario where usuario='" + usuario + "' and pasword='" + pasword + "'";
            datos = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);

            if ("ADMIN".equals(datos.get(0))) {
                mav.setViewName("vistas/Principal");

            } else if ("OPERADOR".equals(datos.get(0))) {
                mav.setViewName("vistas/PrincipalO");
            }
        }
        return mav;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solventar tu problema primero debes aprender a analizar que es lo que retorna el método que estas utilizando por ejemplo: `this.jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);` se puede ver que el tipo de dato que retorna es `List<Map<String, Object>>` entonces tienes una lista y después tiene un map, cuando realizas `"ADMIN".equals(datos.get(0))` lo que estas comparando es si ADMIN es igual a un objeto `Map<String, Object>` lo cual siempre sera `false`, además algunos puntos para mejorar el código serian:

1. Puedes utilizar la primera consulta `datos = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);` para obtener el `tipo`.
2. Debes de acostumbrarte a no concatenar variables en la
   consulta SQL ya que abres una brecha de seguridad para la inyección
   de SQL, además Spring hace muy fácil la tarea de pasar variables a
   la consulta de forma segura.

El Código con las mejoras quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "vistas/validar.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView getValidar(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws SQLException {
        String usuario = req.getParameter("usuario");
        String pasword = req.getParameter("pasword");
        //Iterator<String> it= datos.iterator();
        String sql = "select * from usuario where usuario= ? and pasword= ?";
        // Forma correcta y segura de pasar variables a la consulta SQL
        // datos deberia de ser de tipo List<Map<String, Object>> datos;
        datos = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, usuario, pasword);
        if (datos.isEmpty()) {

            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/index.htm");
        } else {
            // No se necesitan, se obtendran de la primera consulta
            //sql = "select tipo from usuario where usuario='" + usuario + "' and pasword='" + pasword + "'";
            //datos = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);

            String tipo = (String) datos.get(0).get("tipo");

            if ("ADMIN".equals(tipo)) {
                mav.setViewName("vistas/Principal");

            } else if ("OPERADOR".equals(tipo)) {
                mav.setViewName("vistas/PrincipalO");
            }
        }
        return mav;
    }
```

En general según el código que colocaste he modificado para darte una idea, aun hay algunos puntos a mejorar pero con esto deberías tener solventado el problema para validar el tipo de usuario.

Comment: Agradecido, soy nuevo en Spring y es verdad me falta mucho por recorrer, al final pude solucionarlo con tu recomendación.

Comment: Que bien que te haya servido el código para solucionar tú problema, lo importante es ir mejorando un poco cada vez porque aquí todos iniciamos de cero un día.